# 74LS283 4-Bit Adder doesn't work as I expected. It sets some inputs to high voltage

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, measurement, adder

[image]

I bought a few cheap 74LS283 chips. They don't work as I expected.

For some reason it sets the **A1** pin to high voltage (5V) at all times. Considering the **A1** and **B1** pins are supposed to be input pins, it doesn't make any sense to me.

I tried using a pull-down resistor on the **A1** pin, but it doesn't work.

I also measured the voltage of the pins while keeping all of them disconnected (except for the **VCC** and **GND** pins). I put the measurements on the image next to each pin.

Is it supposed to behave this way?

Comment: What value of pulldown resistor did you use?

Comment: "*I bought a few cheap 74LS283 chips.*" This might be your problem. If many of them act the same, they may still be counterfeit or production rejects. The fact that some of the other pins are not solid logic lows is also suspect. It may also be a power supply or bypass capacitor problem. Check voltages with a scope.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the world of bipolar logic, specifically the 74S, 7400, and 74LS families.
Using a pulldown resistor generally won't work, and unused inputs MUST NOT be allowed to float. Rather, unused inputs must be tied either high or low. To tie an input low, ground it. To tie an input high, for the LS family use a 4.7k resistor to +5. Actually, anything between 1k and 10k will work. What you need to do is provide a current of 20 uA per input to pull it above 2 volts. Generally a single resistor can be used to pull up all the unused inputs on a chip.

Another way to do it is to use an unused inverting gate such as an LS00, LS02, LS04, etc. Tie the input low, and you can use the resulting high output.

Unused TTL inputs normally operate as if they are high. However, their input impedance is high, and they can show a remarkable sensitivity to pulses from all sorts of sources, and cause intermittent issues of a remarkable variety of symptoms. So make sure you tie ALL unused inputs of ALL chips either high or low. Keep in mind that tieing inputs low might seem the easiest approach, but you'll be pulling a nominal 400 uA per input, and this can add up quickly, causing both extra current capacity from you power supply and increased power dissipation.

Also note this applies in spades to 74HC series gates. Floating CMOS inputs are even more sensitive than bipolar. Fortunately, for 74HC ICs you can simply tie inputs to either +5 or ground.

I can't stress the need to tie ALL unused inputs to a fixed level. If you let inputs float, even for unused gates on a chip, you can get weird glitches in the sections you are using which will break your heart trying to debug. For beginners making small circuits this usually isn't a problem, but as you get to more complex circuits this can really bite you on the butt, and it will be intermittent and may depend on everything up to and including the phase of the moon. Develop good habits early and save yourself problems.

Comment: +1 Note that LS diode inputs (as used in the 74LS283) can safely be tied directly to +5.  For regular 74 TTL and 74S 1kΩ is recommended (source: TI TTL Databook 1976).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Agreed. But for complete beginners I always recommend as simple a set of guidelines as possible. You never quite know what the buggers will get up to. And for that matter, some early-series LS gates have very low input voltage margins which can be violated by +5 noise if the decoupling isn't up to snuff.

Comment: I tried connecting all the pins to ground using 5.1k resistors, but it doesn't help. The A1 pin is still at high voltage.

Later I tried connecting it directly to ground, but it caused the chip to quickly heat up.

I also noticed the ∑1 pin doesn't react to pins B1 and C0 properly. It seems to somewhat react to them but it stays between 0-1V.

I suspect it might be a faulty batch of chips. I don't know how likely it is. All the other chips I have work just fine. I used at least 16 different chips before, including mostly 74LSxx and CD40xx chips.

Comment: @Altrey - "I tried connecting all the pins to ground using 5.1k resistors, but it doesn't help. " Sigh. Apparently I wasn't clear enough. Tie pins DIRECTLY to ground. When pulling up, use a resistor to +5.